# ChartJs Won't show the third bad, but i can see there is data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So, i cannot figure out why my third bar wont show?!
The data is there, i can see it in the tooltip.

What am i missing?

[image]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart_canvas').getContext('2d');

        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'bar',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: ["BTK", "Dubb", "Ej insmörjd cellplast", "El", "Fogspår/Ursparning", "Lyft", "Yta", "Svetsplåt", "Övrigt"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "SEK Fabrik",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        yAxisID: 'cost_side',
                        data: [result.BTK['cost']['local'], result.Dubb['cost']['local'], result['Ej insmörjd cellplast']['cost']['local'], result.El['cost']['local'], result['Fogspår/Ursparning']['cost']['local'], result.Lyft['cost']['local'], result.Yta['cost']['local'], result.Svetsplåt['cost']['local'], result['Övrigt (element, dörr, fönster, vikt m.m.)']['cost']['local']]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "SEK Montage",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        yAxisID: 'cost_side',
                        data: [result.BTK['cost']['extern'], result.Dubb['cost']['extern'], result['Ej insmörjd cellplast']['cost']['extern'], result.El['cost']['extern'], result['Fogspår/Ursparning']['cost']['extern'], result.Lyft['cost']['extern'], result.Yta['cost']['extern'], result.Svetsplåt['cost']['extern'], result['Övrigt (element, dörr, fönster, vikt m.m.)']['cost']['extern']]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Tid",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                        borderColor: "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        yAxisID: 'time_side',
                        data: [result.BTK['time'], result.Dubb['time'], result['Ej insmörjd cellplast']['time'], result.El['time'], result['Fogspår/Ursparning']['time'], result.Lyft['time'], result.Yta['time'], result.Svetsplåt['time'], result['Övrigt (element, dörr, fönster, vikt m.m.)']['time']]
                    }
                ]
            },
options: {
                resposive: true,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear',
                            stacked: true,
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                                // OR //
                                beginAtZero: true,   // minimum value will be 0.
                                suggestedMax: 2000,
                                autoSkip: false,
                            },
                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'cost_side'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'linear',
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                                // OR //
                                beginAtZero: true,   // minimum value will be 0.
                                suggestedMax: 10,
                                autoSkip: false,
                            },
                            position: 'right',
                            id: 'time_side',
                            gridLines: {drawOnChartArea: false}
                        }

                    ],
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Kostnad "+chosenYear + " " + textMonth + " " + textWeek + " " + textDevice
                }
            }
```

Comment: The data may be too small to render (8.3 compared to 2000 and 3166) - try injecting a larger number to see if it's truly not rendering, otherwise add a snippet with the rendered code, including values, which may make it easier to troubleshoot ...

Comment: I can try this. But i have two axis. and the Yellow bar should be scaled by the right side, so the number should been seen. Also.. when you have small values you can always see the bar if you hover at the bottom.. but the chart even left no place for the yellow bar.. I think it has to do with some code..  but i will try to att a higher value..